# Configure some variables in Powershell when calling doxygen

Tags: powershell, doxygen

How to translate the following behaviour from Windows cmd to Windows Powershell:

```
( type Doxyfile & echo PROJECT_NUMBER=1.0 ) | doxygen.exe -
```

I asked this question already for Windows cmd under
[Configure some variables in command line when calling doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64210353/configure-some-variables-in-command-line-when-calling-doxygen)

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What did you try so far in the Powershell? Which  kind of problems do you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the Powershell does differ a bit. With the aid of other questions I got the following working:

```
&{type Doxyfile; echo PROJECT_NUMBER=1.0} |doxygen -
```

Comment: Thank a lot.
Just need to add another & in front of doxygen (&{type Doxyfile; echo PROJECT_NUMBER=1.0} | & doxygen -) and it is working now.

Comment: I assume you mean the extra `&` after the `|`, for me it was working without the extra `&`, but also the version with `&` works. I tested it with Powershell version  5.1.19041.610, which version did you use (in the powershell the command: $host)

Comment: I used 5.1.18362.752

Comment: Strange that you had to use the extra `$` or did I missed / misread something.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same.
Just started the script without the & and the console says: You must provide some values after "-".

Comment: Strange must be some setting in the powershell in respect to the pipe symbol (`|`), normally a `&` is for combining output (e.g. in `2>&1`). I searhd doxygen for the message you supplied but didn't find it in the source code (and I cannot remember that such type of message exists)

Comment: I am a bit confused. What do you mean with your last sentence.

Comment: I think a typo hit the sentence:  I searched doxygen for the message you supplied but didn't find it in the source code (and I cannot remember that such type of message exists). i.e. I looked in the doxygen source code to see whether I could find any evidence of `You must provide some values after "-"` or something similar but I didn't find anything and cannot remember that I ever saw something like it.